# Convert a Lambda expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm still trying to understand lambda expressions.

I'd like to convert this lambda expression into a "normal" expression:

```
float evaluate = Arrays.stream(queries).mapToInt(query -> 
(query.getCategory().equals(this.classify(this.retrieve(query, database, featureType), k)) ? 1 : 0)).sum();
```

you guys have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal expression"?

Comment: well.. in a non-lambda-expression way

Comment: I think this is not the best snippet to get a grasp of lambda expressions. The whole `query.getCategory().equals(this.classify(this.retrieve(query, database, featureType), k)) ? 1 : 0)` has nothing to do with lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the following code to your needs

The Lambda expression in your example "is a" ToIntFunction
(e.g. in Eclipse you can even switch between the two versions by pressing Ctrl+1 / Convert...)

```
    String[] queries = null;
    float evaluate = Arrays.stream(queries).mapToInt(
        new ToIntFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public int applyAsInt(String query) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    ).sum();
```

is the same as

```
float evaluate = Arrays.stream(queries).mapToInt(query -> 0).sum();
```

Comment: Much cleaner would be to move it to a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
With some assumptions..

float evaluate = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(Query query : queries) {
        int categoryTypeFromDb = this.classify(this.retrieve(query, database, featureType), k) ? 1 : 0;
        if(query.getCategory().equals(categoryTypeFromDb)) {
            sum += categoryTypeFromDb;
        }
    }
    evaluate = sum;
```